# What is a good time between synchronizing jobs?

Tags: android, performance, notifications

After discovering that WhatsApp probably updates notifications about every second I began to wonder what the best combination of battery life and keeping users up to date by notifications is.

The company where I work right now is really afraid of sucking the battery life. So they want the fastest sync to be around a quarter. Meanwhile WhatsApp updates every second. So is what our company doing the right thing? Or can we just like WhatsApp check for new updates every second because it doesn't suck that much battery life?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That extensive network usage will surely be very expensive for battery and even for data usage. If you need frequently updated data in your app, in most of the cases it's a bad practice to send HTTP request once per 1 (2 or  even 5) seconds.

A good way to receive and update any kind of notification (wether it's Android system notification or some notification badge inside your app) is using Google Cloud Messaging. You'll have to implement it on both server and client side. You will need to register your app package name in [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com) and retrieve an API key. After you do that, your app will be able to receive push notification from GCM server. The flow of receiving a push notification looks like this:

- You register current device to GCM system using provided SDK and it generates you GCM unique identifier of current device
- You upload this key to your server (if you have user profiles in your app architecture, it's a good idea to store it in current user profile)
- Once something important happens on server, say, user gets a new unread message, your server takes the GCM unique identifier from user profile and sends a notification to GCM server
- GCM server sends this data to user's device by using this identifier and delivers the notification to your implementation of a `BroadcastReciever`. After that it's up to you what to do with this data: create a system notification or/and use this information to update UI of your app.

It is just an overview of how does Google Cloud Messaging work, there are tons of articles about how to set it up and implement into your project, for example, [this one](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Cloud-Messaging). This solution might look way more complicated than just sending HTTP request every second, but your potential users will be thankful for saved battery and data limit.

Also, if you want to make Android system notifications, you may want to use [Parse](https://parse.com/docs) library which wraps GCM and makes implementation a bit easier.